# Creating a JavaDoc with specific settings for one class

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a JavaDoc that I would like to create where only public methods are included, except for a specific class, that is abstract and must be implemented by the user, where the protected methods must be documented as well.

Currently I am accomplishing this by generating two JavaDocs using Eclipse, one public and one protected, then replacing the file in the public JavaDoc with the one from the protected JavaDoc.

**Is there a simpler way to accomplish this task?** I can't seem to find a setting in Eclipse that will allow me to select an individual file for extra documentation.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why you feel this is necessary.  If you are designing an API for use by external clients, then both the public classes and class members AS WELL AS the protected members and the abstract methods extended by them are certifably, definitely, absolutely part of your exported API and they should be documented in the same JavaDoc.  I don't think it feels right to have users of your exported API fish for information in different places.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with ant. I think eclipse cant do this by its self.

[Ant javadoc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html)

Example:

```
<javadoc
       destdir="docs/api"
       author="true"
       version="true"
       use="true"
       windowtitle="Test API">
</javadoc>
```